# Assign values from another table to another table SQLITE

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm currently creating a database application and i have a problem with sql syntax and maybe my database is incorrect.

I have two tables:

```
USERS

id_user | login | password | name | surname | position

1         test     test      Jan    Kowalski    IT

COMPUTERS

id_computer | name | model | serial | os | cpu | ram

1            HP   Q445    XXXYYY    Ubuntu  2x2GHz 4GB
```

I would like to assign this computer to user, but it's not working in 100%..

```
   SELECT users.id_user, computers.* FROM users LEFT JOIN computers ON computers.id_computer= users.id WHERE users.id = 1
```

Maybe i should add to table "users" next column with devices?

Before use INSERT INTO to add row, first i need to bind/relate these two tables and i dont know how.

I would like to add this record to user and next read this row and display in my application(in Java Swing).

Comment: In the database you have to relate computers to users in some way. Are they one-to-one related? (Just one computer per user and viceverse)

Comment: You should take a SQL tutorial first.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have relate these tables. I am learning sqlite and i dont know how to bind columns in database :( I know that to Insert values i need to use INSERT INTO but before i would like to test syntax SELECT but not working for other users

Comment: You cannot simply use SELECT; you need to add more data to define a relationship between these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table USERS and COMPUTERS need to be related by a foreign key. I would suggest the relation is one to many between USERS and COMPUTERS, so in  theory at least a user can have more than one computer. To achieve this add an extra field to the COMPUTER table called id_user this is the foreign key that will give the link between the two tables. In that field you put the id_user of the person using the computer. So you can now do a select query with a join on the users.id_user and computers.id_user fields.

```
SELECT users.id_user, computers.* FROM users LEFT JOIN computers ON users.id_user = computers.id_user;
```

The LEFT JOIN you used will select all users whether they have a computer or not. If you have not already, then make id_user and id_computer the unique primary keys of their tables. Perhaps consider an AUTOINCREMENT on these fields.

Notes:

1. I have used upper and lower case for table names as you did to help your understanding, but note you are not consistent. Also your select query has the field id which is not in  your table schema.
2. [Link to a tutorial on the concepts of relational databases that you may find helpful as you progress with your project](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much!